# Getting more than one entry from a table and adding them

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get the reputation of a union (everyone who is in the unions reputation added)

```
 $the_member = mysql_query("SELECT `reputation` FROM `stats` WHERE `id` in (SELECT `id`   FROM `user` WHERE `union`='".$id."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Thats what I have So far and if you echo it its just blank, no errors and no text.

Comment: First of all, read a little about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: You schouldn't use php mysql_ lib. That one is depracted. Look up mysqli or PDO instead. Also check out SQL injections as mentioned above!

Answer (score 0):

If you read the PHP doc for [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), you'll see an example that shows you how to use it. Basically you need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` (or some similar function) to get the actual data, like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($the_member)) {
  echo $row['reputation'];
}
```

**Warning**: try not to use `mysql_query`, it's deprecated. Use `mysqli_query`, or better yet, `PDO`. It's all in the link above. Also, you need to make sure the `$id` value doesn't contain anything that would break your query. This is called ["SQL injection"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), and in certain cases it lets anyone run an arbitrary query. Consider the case when `$id == "'); drop table user; --"`

Comment: I have this code and it doesnt even echo out "test" not to mention the reputation!

Comment: $the_member = mysql_query("SELECT `reputation` FROM `stats` WHERE `id` in (SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `union`='".$id."')") or die(mysql_error());
   
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($the_member)) {
    echo "test".$row['reputation'];
}

Comment: Did you try running the query directly in the MySQL console?